# Inject custom provider value inside swagger decorator in NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, swagger, decorator

I currently have a module that defines a controller with one endpoint. This module is imported by multiple applications to inherit that endpoint. Everything works fine. However, my issue is that I generate Swagger documentation in all of my applications and i would like to adapt the ApiOkResponse for this endpoint depending on the application using it.

My module looks like:

```js
  export class MyEndpointModule {
  static register(apiReturnSchema: SchemaObject & Partial<ReferenceObject>): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: MyEndpointModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'SCHEMA_TEST',
          useValue: apiReturnSchema,
        },
        ...
```

and i import is as :

```js
  MyEndpointModule.register({ 
    oneOf: [
      {$ref: getSchemaPath(schema1)},
      {$ref: getSchemaPath(schema2)},
    ]
  }),
```

and the idea was to set the controller of my MyEndpointModule like :

```js
export class MyController {
  constructor(
    @Inject('SCHEMA_TEST') private schemaTest: SchemaObject & Partial<ReferenceObject>
  ) {}

   @ApiOkResponse({
    description: 'blabla',
    schema: this.schemaTest,
  })
```

but I can not use this inside a decorator. I'm stuck from this point. How could I solve this?